# can jquery callback function of load method be a custom function

Tags: jquery, callback

I was wondering if the `load()` method can be a custom function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").load(url, myfunc());
});
```

the `myfunc()` is a custom function. Or if that doesnot work,can the callback function calls a another custom function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").load(url, function(){
        myfunc();
    })
;});
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you are *invoking* the function-object that `myfunc` evaluates to *immediately*. (Take off the extra parenthesis.)

Comment: @pst: I now it's a rather old and trivial question but I think you should provide your comment as an answer.